# Open source Linux vpnc client that can connect to checkpoint gateway

Tags: linux, networking, security, vpn

I need an open source vpnc client that can connect to a [Check Point](http://www.checkpoint.com) gateway (firewall) for a Linux machine. It doesn't matter which Linux (red-hat, ubuntu, fedora...).

The target is to activate the vpnc bi CLI command (not GUI interface). It is very strange that I can't find a Linux vpnc for checkpoints, but for Cisco there is more than one.

*Please not suggest vpnc the. SSL Network Extender (SNX), because they require additional configuration on the gateway, and we can't make any change on the customer side.*